# amazon MWS sandbox login error

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating shopping website. In this site i trying to provide pay with amazon for customer,
I am referring LoginandPaywithAmazon-dotnet-1.0.10_US (ASP.Net c#) sample for development,

Here my problem, I am not able to login into amazon using my existing amazon id (created in Amazon.com) it throws error message
[image]

if i create id via my application it works fine,
i don't know the reason for this error. I am looking forward for your help.

Comment: I need to integrate amazon users account into My website, I am following this link http://login.amazon.com/documentation/combining-user-accounts as reference, I don't get clearly how to integrate help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in sandbox mode you will need to use a test account credentials. Test accounts for sandbox can be created in Seller Central by clicking on "Integration" then "Test Accounts".